# Converting decimal value of byte's into byte's again

Tags: java, string, casting, integer, byte

I am using FileInputStream to read bytes from class file, in order to get all 4 characters Strings from it(By string I mean any sequence of 4 bytes corresponding to letters or digits in ASCII code). I want to save them in temp arrays(or ArrayLists) of size 4, and then threw them into one bigger ArrayList. However I' ve stucked with converting readed bytes(FileInputStream returns me int which is decimal value of byte) into bytes again in order to use String constructor ( String(byte[] bytes) ).

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> dozapisu = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Byte> temp = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    int c;
    File klasowe = new File("C:/Desktop/do testu/Kalendarz.class");
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(klasowe);
        while((c=fis.read()) != -1){
            if((c >= 48 && c <= 57) || (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || (c >= 97 && c <= 122)){
                temp.add(new Byte((byte) c));
            }else{
                if(temp.size()==4){
                //  dozapisu.add(*/How should I add them?/*);
                }
            }
        }


        fis.close();
    }catch(IOException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    } 
}
```

So, my question is how to cast those readen Integers into bytes again. Forgive me my shity English, if you don't understand my question please ask for more translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
byte [] bytes = new byte[4];
int counter = 0;
while((c = fis.read()) != -1){
    if((c >= 48 && c <= 57) || (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || (c >= 97 && c <= 122)){
        bytes[counter] = (byte)c;
        counter++;
        if(counter == 4){
            // do things with 4 byte array
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If I am not wrong you need things like above, right?

Using bytes array will be better than having Lists, I think. Just keep track how much bytes array has filled. When it becomes 4 byte in array, process that full 4 byte array, then reset back counter for array.

**EDIT:**

To create string from bytes, you can use:

```
byte [] bytes = new byte[4];
int counter = 0;
while((c = fis.read()) != -1){
    if((c >= 48 && c <= 57) || (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || (c >= 97 && c <= 122)){
        bytes[counter] = (byte)c;
        counter++;
        if(counter == 4){
            // do things with 4 byte array
            String str = new String(bytes);
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The string str will be created from four bytes. Is that you need?

Comment: This part is quite easy for me, my problems lays in casting those integer c(stoting ascii value) into representation of it, so for example, if c=99, what Should I do to receive String ="c". Assuming that in ascii 99 is equal to lower case c.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is right, I must had some sort of brain lag :)

Comment: There is a typo. It should be: `if (counter == 4)`

Comment: @user278064 Thanks :) I just written code without compiling it.